# Msal problem for Edge: Hash does not contain state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure-ad-msal

I'm having a problem with Msal (Microsoft SSO) on Microsoft Edge. For some reason, the login call always fails and gives the following error:

```
AuthError: Unexpected error in authentication.: Hash does not contain state
```

A little bit more background about my code. Here it goes wrong:

```js
var SSO = new $window.Msal.UserAgentApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: self.clientId,
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
});

SSO.loginPopup({
    scopes: ['user.read'],
    prompt: 'select_account'
}).then(function(res) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('FAILURE');
    console.log(e);
});
```

I am using Msal version 1.2.1 (the latest one which released mid January) and all browsers work fine (even IE11) except for Edge. Am I doing something wrong or has anyone encountered something similar and was able to resolve this issue?

Thanks!